# Convert MongoDate using moment.js

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, momentjs

I am pulling information from a Mongo database using JavaScript and I get the data in the following json format:

```
end_date : {
sec: 1453532400,
usec: 0,
__proto__: Object
}
```

The problem I am running into is trying to convert that date to be a JavaScript DATE_RFC2822 or ISO format. I am using moment.js like this with no results:

```
moment(response.end_date).toISOString())
```

It always returns the current date and time. My question is how should I be converting MongoDates in JavaScript to DATE_RFC2822 or ISO formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sec` property is a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can send in that property only:

```
moment(response.end_date.sec, "X").toISOString()
```

or alternatively:

```
moment.unix(response.end_date.sec).toISOString()
```

Comment: The second answer is right, the first one gives a date from 1970

Comment: Fixed. I read the [format table](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) too fast.

Comment: Or alternatively without moment `new Date(response.end_date.sec * 1000).toISOString();`